# How to dynamically switch control of USB powered devices?

Tags: android, usb

Cross posted this on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135686/how-to-dynamically-switch-control-of-usb-powered-devices) but haven't got a response just yet.

I am looking for ways on how I can dynamically switch apps on my android device that use/control the USB-powered device. For now, all I can do is to connect/disconnect the USB and when the dialog pops-up, switch to the app I want to control. But I want to switch apps dynamically without having to connect/disconnect the USB.

Even if I detect that the USB is detached, I am unable to switch apps dynamically. Is this a limitation of AOA protocol or am I missing a trick here?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is a limitation. You cant switch apps dynamically by sending the Vendor Requests. Why can't you try to establish a communication between the two apps in the phone itself.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to cut the VBUS on the accessory side for at least 1 second, and send the Vendor requests for the second app.

Comment: @skylinedreamer I am not sure if I understand your last comment "...cut the VBUS on the accessory...". The problem we are running into is we are unable to detect USB connect/disconnect consistently even though we are listening for `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED` or `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED`

Comment: Check out this link (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61390&can=1&q=aoa&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

Comment: Some phones behave erroneously if it's unplugged, when it was reading data from the host. The reader states are not updated in the driver layer in such scenarios. [Explained in the link above] Due to this issue Samsung and Sony phones  gets rebooted most of the time. Where as some phones might need sometime to stabilize before its plugged in again to switch to AOA mode. May I know what phone you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the link; I tried Samsung, Xiaomi among other devices and the behavior is very much the same.

Comment: one way to prevent this behaviour is to have a "safely remove" mechanism in the phone, which closes the reading task before unplugging.